# SVG Animation rotate

Tags: svg, rotation

I've got a very annoying Problem using rotations in my SVG Animation. The problem is: I have an object, which I want to move along a specific path. So far it works well. But if I try to rotate this object at the end of the path it doesn't work. Sometimes my Object disappears because it's outside the viewbox and I have to try many values for the x and y values of the rotate statement until it works. And then it only works if I set the duration to 0.001s so it rotates instant, because actually my object switches to a much higher point in the viewbox and begins to rotate and only the final position is right but you see it rotating down or up around any point so it doesn't really work. I have no idea how to get the x and y values which I need to rotate the object around its own axis. Here is the code example, I hope you know how to solve this problem:

```
<defs>
  <g id="Karte" visibility="hidden">
  <!--Karte-->
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="980" height="550" style="stroke: none; fill: rgb(189,248,137)" />
  <!--Straßen-->
    <path id="Straße1" d="M 510 0 L 510 120 0 120 0 150 980 150 980 120 540 120 540 0" style="stroke: none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <rect id="Straße2" x="0" y ="320" width="980" height="20" style="stroke:none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <rect id="Straße3" x="0" y="500" width="980" height="30" style="stroke:none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <rect id="Straße4" x="25" y="340" width="30" height="160" style="stroke:none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <rect id="Straße5" x="930" y="340" width="30" height="160" style="stroke:none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <path id="campus" d="M 515 150 L 515 170 510 170 510 300 525 300 525 320 650 320 650 300 665 300 665 170 545 170 545 150" style="stroke:none; fill: lightgrey" />
    <polyline id="rampe1" points="570,300 570,307 635,317 635,320" style="stroke-width: 1; fill:none" />
    <polyline id="rampe2" points="580,300 580,303 645,313 645,320" style="stroke-width: 1; fill:none" />
    <g id="Treppe1">
    <line x1="515" y1="153" x2="545" y2="153" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="515" y1="157" x2="545" y2="157" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="515" y1="161" x2="545" y2="161" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="515" y1="165" x2="545" y2="165" stroke-width="0.5" />
    </g>
    <g id="Treppe2">
    <line x1="525" y1="303" x2="565" y2="303" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="525" y1="307" x2="565" y2="307" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="525" y1="311" x2="565" y2="311" stroke-width="0.5" />
    <line x1="525" y1="315" x2="565" y2="315" stroke-width="0.5" />
    </g>
    <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="0s" />

  </g>
  </defs>


  <!--Figuren-->

  <defs>

    <g id="John" visibility="hidden">
    <circle cx="520" cy="100" r="5" />
    <line x1="520" y1="104" x2="520" y2="115" stroke-width="2" />
    <line x1="520" y1="104" x2="520" y2="117" stroke-width="1" />
    <polyline points="520,100 523.5,108 520,112" style="fill:none" /> 
    <polyline points="520,100 514,104 520,108" style="fill:none" /> 
    <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="0s" />
    </g>


  </defs>


    <!--Animation-->
    <use xlink:href="#Karte" />

    <use x="420" y="360" transform="rotate(90 910 490)" xlink:href="#John" >
    <animateMotion path="M 0 0 L -900 -10" begin="0s" dur="6s" fill="freeze" />
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="90 940 490" to="180 940 490" begin="6s" dur="0.001" fill="freeze"/>
    <animateMotion path="M-900 -10 L -900 -190" begin="6.01s" dur="3.98s" fill="freeze" />
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="180 970 490" to="270 970 490" begin="10s" dur="0.001" fill="freeze"/>
    <animateMotion path="M -900 -190 L -450 -190" begin="10.01" dur="4.98" fill="freeze" />
    <animateTransform  attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="270 940 490" to="180 940 490" begin="15s" dur="0.001" fill="freeze"/>
    <animateMotion path="M -450 -190 L -390 -190" begin="15" dur="1" fill="freeze" />
    </use>



  </svg>
```

Comment: Can you detail your problem showing exactly where it is happening? (I see a circle moving, and don't understand what you mean by it not rotating - can you describe what part of your code you are talking about)? You might want to include this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/D2EWP/) and edit it if necessary.

Comment: I'm talking about the part where the Animation takes place. The Problem is I don't know how to find out the coordinates I need for the rotation if I moved or rotated my Object (in this case, a stickfigure) once before. I got all the coordinates of the rotate-animations in my code just by trying many different values for the x and y coordinates. I just want to know how to get these Points by calculating them, because I have more Objects to move and dont want to try every possible value to find the right value to let them rotate where they are in the animation. I hope you got my point.